# how to extract a negative symbol from text

Tags: c#, linq

Below I have a piece of code that is able to extract the number values from a piece of text. So if I have string `+12 is on same day`, then it will extract 12.

However if I have a negative number like `-12 is on the same day,` I want it to extract -12, not 12.

How I can extract the minus symbol?

```
foreach (char c in alternativeAirportPrice.Text)
{
    if (char.IsNumber(c))
    {                    
        string test = "-12 on same day";
        string alternativeAirportPriceValue = string.Join("", test.ToCharArray()
                                             .Where(x => char.IsDigit(x)).ToArray());
        return alternativeAirportPriceValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: The code is not very stable at all. Think about "9 is the new 11" and it will return "911"

Comment: That's a good point; @bruceybandit do you know that there will always only be one number in the text?

Comment: @SirRufo I think it's a great feature when dangerous code pops up the right number to call.

Comment: @GertArnold - I think you'd need to take localisation into account though ;)

Comment: [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 5):

You can use a regex pattern:

```
-?\d+
```

This will match any string of digits or a `-` followed by a string of digits.

```
string text = "-12 on the same day";
var match = Regex.Match(text, "-?\\d+");
return match.Value;
```

Remember to add a using directive to `System.Text.RegularExpressions`!

Comment: I like that. As sir Rufo says above though it depends if the original poster knows only one number is present, as this will return the first one

Answer (score 2):

This should be what you want based on the question's desired result. Note that you don't need a `foreach` loop for this purpose just LINQ is enough:

```
string.Join("", test.Split(' ').Where(x => int.TryParse(x , out _)).ToArray());
return alternativeAirportPriceValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public IEnumerable<int> ExtractNumbers(string text)
{
    text += " ";
    var temp = string.Empty;
    for (var i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
    {
        if (char.IsDigit(text[i]))
        {
            if ('-'.Equals(text[i - 1]))
            {
                temp += text[i - 1];
            }
            temp += text[i];
        }
        else if (temp.Length > 0)
        {
            yield return int.Parse(temp);
            temp = string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

This way you can handle cases where the string has multiple numbers in it, as observed by @Sir Rufo

The line:

```
text += " ";
```

is there to ensure the loop will hit the "else if" block when a number is in the last position of the string, e.g. "-12 on the same day 123456"